# Downloading XLS with Python using Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, download

My goal is to download the XLS file from every day of a specific month. However, when I inspect, with the developer tools of chrome, the download button of the XLS file it is not a button at all. So how can I download the XLS? Here the HTML of the "button" which is not a button...

```
<div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download XLS</div>
```

This class is inside another class. Here the complete code

```
<div class="highcharts-menu" style="box-shadow: rgb(136, 136, 136) 3px 3px 10px; border: 1px solid rgb(153, 153, 153); background: rgb(255, 255, 255); padding: 5px 0px;">
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Print chart</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download PNG image</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download JPEG image</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download PDF document</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download SVG vector image</div>
    <hr>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download CSV</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Download XLS</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">View data table</div>
    <div class="highcharts-menu-item" style="cursor: pointer; padding: 0.5em 1em; color: rgb(51, 51, 51); background: none; font-size: 11px; transition: background 250ms ease 0s, color 250ms ease 0s;">Open in Highcharts Cloud</div></div>
```

Plus the Xpath is always changing, How can I download that XLS File? Thanks a lot!

Comment: can you please share the url of the application if it's public? Can you see the url from where the file is getting downloaded?

Comment: Unfortunately, the web page is not public. No, I can't see the URL from where the file is getting downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

This is `div` element used as container. This is also not have `onClick()` event. By html its not seems clickable element but you are able to click manually. You can give it a try with below code.

It will find element, if it will be clickable then it will click.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


    myElem = WebDriverWait(driver, delay).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[.= 'Download XLS']")))

    If(myElem.is_enabled() and myElem.is_displayed()):

    myElem.click()
```